# Int limit of 5 and when I add a sixth number, I don't want it to erase the next one

Tags: html, css, angular

If exemple, I have an input with a max lenght of 5 int, "12345" and put a 9 after the "3" its going to erase the next number ("4") so its going to be "12395".

I would like to just block so i cant enter anything if there is already 5 int inside the input.

I use html and angular 7, this is my input mask that i'm using

```
    return createNumberMask({
        includeThousandsSeparator: true,
        thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '',
        allowDecimal: false,
        allowNegative: false,
        integerLimit: 5,
        suffix: '',
        prefix: ''
    });
}
```

Comment: You can do this in your template, with a custom Pipe, with form validation, or as a custom service. I would like to see a little more of your code before posting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

max-length of an input will not allow anymore characters, you must remove one before adding a new one

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="5"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[max length](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Comment: maxlength works but I want only numbers and if I put add type="number" the maxlength stops working

Comment: ok I got it, i mixed both max-length="5" (without type="number") + my input mask that I mentionned on top thank you!